# Electron app's system tray icon is blank on Windows, works fine on Mac OS

Tags: javascript, windows, electron, electron-builder

I'm working on adding a system tray icon to my Electron app. On Mac OS, the icon works as expected. The icon shows in the system tray and can be interacted with as intended. On Windows, the functionality of the system tray icon is there (e.g. there's a space for the icon, I can right-click on the icon and interact with the dropdown menu properly), but the actual icon isn't there in the space where it should be.

Here's the code for this:

```js
let tray
let iconPath
let trayIcon
let contextMenu

function createTray(){

    iconPath = path.join(__dirname, '../public/img/trayicon.png');
    trayIcon = nativeImage.createFromPath(iconPath);
    trayIcon = trayIcon.resize({ width: 16, height: 16 });
    tray = new Tray(trayIcon);
    contextMenu = Menu.buildFromTemplate([
      { label: 'Toggle Chronos', click(){ toggleMainWindow(); } },
      { label: 'Quit', click() { app.quit() } }
    ]);
    tray.setContextMenu(contextMenu);
}
```

[Screenshot of the blank system tray icon on Windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DsvTA.png)

[Screenshot of how it looks on Mac OS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZSeC.png)

I've tried swapping the icon out to an .ico hoping that it's just Windows being unable to display a PNG in the system tray, but that just breaks it on Mac OS too without fixing it on Windows.